# How can i get the row and column index of a cell in a listview?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, gridview

I have a WPF application with a listview being represented by a gridview in the UI. I want to have an event that when a cell in this list view is clicked i can see the row and the column index of cell. Currently i can get the entire list item (the row) but not the column which is clicked.

For example my list view looks like this:
[List view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv0n4.png)

When the email address sammy.doe@gmail.com is clicked the row=2 and column=2 should be available in the event handler, and when the age 39 is clicked row=1 and column=1 should be available.

How is it possible to get this information in the click event handler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this problem for a couple of day i have found a solution my using the mouse point location on a click event. And then searching through the Gridview columns to find which column this lays in by considering the X position of the pointer.

Heres my code behind:

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Dim items As List(Of User) = New List(Of User)
        items.Add(New User() With {.Name = "Isaac", .Age = 23, .Email = "isaac@email.co.uk", .City = "London", .Phone = "123456789"})
        items.Add(New User() With {.Name = "Jacob", .Age = 29, .Email = "jacob@email.co.uk", .City = "Royston", .Phone = "214563255"})
        lv.ItemsSource = items

        Me.DataContext = Me
    End Sub


    Private Sub Lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
        Dim gv = DirectCast(lv.View, GridView)
        Dim lvi = DirectCast(sender, ListViewItem)
        Dim p = e.GetPosition(lvi)
        Dim c_n = GetColumnNumber(gv, p)
        Debug.Print("Row: " + lv.SelectedIndex.ToString + "     Column: " + c_n.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetColumnNumber(gv As GridView, p As Point) As Integer
        Dim n As Integer = 0
        Dim columnFound As Boolean = False
        Dim leftSide = 0
        Dim rightSide = 0
        For Each c In gv.Columns
            rightSide += c.ActualWidth
            If InRange(leftSide, rightSide, p.X) Then
                columnFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
            leftSide = rightSide
            n += 1
        Next
        If Not columnFound Then n = Nothing
        Return n
    End Function

    Public Function InRange(lower As Double, upper As Double, value As Double) As Boolean
        If value < upper And value > lower Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class



Public Class User
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property City As String
End Class
```

And here is my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSelection"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="List View Selection" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lv">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Phone" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope this can help someone else.